# WPF/Silverlight: How do I create a BehaviorCollection on a control that doesn't already have one?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

How do I create a BehaviorCollection on a control that doesn't already have one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API for this isn't so obvious, to do in code use the following:

```
var behaviorCollection = System.Windows.Interactivity.Interaction
                                          .GetBehaviors(controlToAddBehaviorTo);
behaviorCollection.Add(new MyBehavior());
```

where obviously `controlToAddBehaviorTo` is the "control that doesn't already have one".

For the same thing in xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="controlToAddBehaviorTo">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:MyBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

with an import for the interactivity namespace `xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

Comment: I would have never found that on my own.